# WebAPI Threading

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-web-api

So I have a function that has a long wait time during its computation. I have a endpoint that needs to call this function, however it does not care about the completion of the function.

```
public HttpResponseMessage endPoint
{
    Repository repo= new Repository();
    // I want repo.computeLongFunction(); to be called, however this endpoint
    // can return a http status code "ok" even if the long function hasn't completed.

    repo.computeLongFunction();

    return Request.CreateReponse(HttpStatusCode.Ok);
}

// If I make the function async would that work?
public class Repository
{ 
    public void compluteLongFunction()
    { 

    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if the method fails? Does anyone care?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the Task Parallel Library (TPL) to spin off a new thread.

```
Task.Run(() => new Repository().computeLongFunction());
return Request.CreateReponse(HttpStatusCode.Ok);
```

Comment: So even if the calling function ends, the spawned thread will continue?

Comment: Spinning off a new Task via Task.Run does not actually create a new Thread.  The computeLongFunction work item will be scheduled to run as soon as resources become available.

So yes, this is a good approach especially when running within an ASP.NET application; it is best to avoid creating threads directly.

Comment: You should try and create some kind of mechanism though that allows the user to look in on the completion status of the scheduled task.

Comment: if the task fails it will throw an unhandled exception - in general, it's a bad practice to fire and forget tasks

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like computeLongFunction() returns anything, so try this:

```
Thread longThread = new Thread(() => new Repository().computeLongFunction());
longThread.Start();

return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Ok);
```

Declare the thread so that you will still be able to control its life-cycle.

Comment: Directly interacting with threads is generally frowned upon these days -- there are a number of nice abstractions on top of threads in the TPL. There are still reasons to interact with threads directly, but it generally falls in the category of "only if you know exactly what you're doing and why you're doing it"

Comment: you can do the same with a task - adding the LongRunningTask option at the task creation